# How to import a SQLite db file into DbVisualizer

Tags: sqlite, import, dbvisualizer

How can a SQLite *.db file be imported into DbVisualizer?
Since the SQLite database file extension is *.db how can we load this into DbVisualizer to view the tables and generate the ER diagram?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In DbVisualizer open **Tools->Connection Wizard**. In the **Select Database Driver** pane pick **SQLite** from the list and click **Next**.

In the last details pane load the file (.db or .sqlite) in the **Database file name** field. Click **Finish** and you should be connected.

Comment: On Windows, make sure not to have quotes around the file path.

Answer (score 2):

On version 23.1 I couldn't find the option described in the [initial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618509/4163938).
It is actually a little bit easier. **Database** > **Create Database Connection** and search SQLite, then you will see the field **Database file name**.