# How to generate SQLite entity relationship diagram from database file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, entity-relationship

I am trying to  reverse engineering to a database file that an android application generates. It gives me a SQLite file in .db extension. I tried pass it through SQLite Browser and it gets me the tables, but no relationships also every table givesme "id" for primary key. Any help or suggestions on how to approach this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MySQL workbench select `Database` option from the menus available on the top of the screen,there you will get `reverse engineer` option. Click on it then select your server and database on which you want to create `ER` diagram and click next.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. so I have to install something like Xampp to run a server?

Comment: Yes, Xampp  is required.

Answer (score 20):

After extensive search, I found that you can do it without running a server using [DBVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/).
After you install DBVisualizer, [import your database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618509/17595968), then expand the database connection which is on the left under **Connections**, expand **schema** then double click **Tables**. Switch to **References** tab in the pane on the right and you'll have your diagram.

I have also found about [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/getting-started.html) which is free and open source unlike DBVisualizer and also doesn't require running a server, but have yet to get it to work. You can follow [this guide](https://gist.github.com/dannguyen/f056d05bb7fec408bb7c14ea1552c349) if you wish to use this instead.

[Example of ER diagram generated by DBVisualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuw0B.png)

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way to do this is by using the [SchemaCrawler web application](https://www.schemacrawler.com/webapp.html). If you need to keep your database private, you can use the approach suggested by @freshpasta

Comment: That link gives a 404 ...

Answer (score 3):

> For me it worked using `DBeaver universal database`

[SQLite file in .db extension to ER diagram.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp-ZM5_9KgU)

[image: ER diagram sqlite3 database]

Answer (score 2):

A bit late but if you got IntelliJ IDE product you can connect to your "Database" and generate a diagram for it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-diagrams.html

Note: IntelliJ is paid tool,so you may need a paid version for this trick
Or just enable free trial till you do this task.

**References**
https://www.jetbrains.com/products/compare/?product=idea&product=idea-ce
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/

Answer (score 1):

using [DBVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/)

1. click [DOWNLOAD FOR FREE]
2. install and selecet [free forever] at the end, Note:(could not find a way change to trail after)
3. run the app and click [+] to add a new data base connection
4. type [SQLite] in search bar
5. under [Database file name] click the drop down arrow and load file
6. follow [freshpasta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70269488/22015116) answer: expand the following [created data base>Schema] then click on [Tables] to [Open Object] and select [References] tab. which shows the entity relationship diagram.